# why does the main app scss file in ionic 4 not work?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I've been working on an ionic app, I've come to do some styling on it and I'm having issues with app.scss.

According to the ionic documents I should be able to use app.scss for app-wide styles such as the toolbar etc. but nothing happens when I try to style anything from this file, it's like it's not being included in the build?

The initial project was done by creating the app in CLI with the sidebar menu option as the template and all the scss files work fine in the individual components.

Any idea why the app.scss file isn't working? I've inspected elements I've tried to style and they are not being picked up at all.

An example:

```css
ion-title {
  background: red;
}
```

this doesn't work, the toolbar background doesn't change, but it does through chrome inspector.

I have tried this in global.scss too and still nothing, funny thing is if I apply a display:none to all elements it works:

```css
* {
  display: none;
}
```

it just doesn't seem to want to style individual elements like the "ion-title"

**UPDATE:**

There seems to be a bug in ionic 4, the styleUrls won't accept me adding ../app.scss , it throws an error, but I can include ../app.css so I'm just going to auto-compile the scss to css.

I can then include the app.css file in each component and it's working!

Comment: Can you try changing it to global.scss instead of app.scss? I'm working on an ionic 4 project now and all of my global styles in that work

Comment: @ConnorH I'm sure I've tried that and same result, let me try again and come back to you.

Comment: @ConnorH ok so I have updated my question with an example, doesn't work in Global.scss either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in ionic 4, the styleUrls won't accept me adding ../app.scss , it throws an error, but I can include ../app.css so I'm just going to auto-compile the scss to css.

I can then include the app.css file in each component and it's working!

Answer (score 3):

In Ionic 4, global styles are saved by default in src/app/global.scss

If this is an Angular project that you are converting from an Ionic 3 template, you must add a reference to your global scss file in your angular.json file in under projects/app/architect/build/styles, like below

```html
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
  },
  {
    "input": "src/global.scss"
  }
],
```

This is a change from Ionic 3 where it used to be in src/app/app.scss. If you created a project in Ionic 3 or earlier, you must move your styles into a new global.scss for them to be applied throughout the whole app

Comment: Doesn't work mate, I edited my question above, just simply trying to change the background of ion-title doesn't work

Comment: I forgot to mention the reference in angular.json. I updated the answer above

Comment: It was an angular 4 project from the start, and global.scss is already in the angular.json file. It loads in because I can put a wildcard style like *{display:none;} which hides everything, it just won't seem to style individual elements like ion-title. The strange thing is, I can style all the elements from within each component's own scss file but I don't want to be repeating them for every component

Answer (score 0):

You must include the path of app.scss file in your app.component.ts like this

```
styleUrls: ['app.scss']
```

Then you will be able to use your scss file

Comment: Hi , I tried this, I just get an error: Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings  at assertArrayOfStrings after I include it like this: styleUrls: ['app.scss']